# Titanium: Is there anyway to fire an event when an imageView starts to load an image?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I want to display an indicator that an image is loading.  I can successfully stop the indicator with the 'load' event, but is there any way to fire an event when the image view starts to load my remote image?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

if your indicator inside the image and the remote image doesn't contain alpha color, use this and you dont need to handle any event when image load it's will hide the indicator

```
<View height="Ti.UI.SIZE" width="Ti.UI.SIZE>
    <ActivityIndicator visible="true"/>
    <ImageView backgroundColor="transparent" image="https//..."/>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do that.

1. Show activity indicator when you set remote link and hide that on load event.
2. Use httpClient to download image and show indicator before calling xhr request and hide it on Success or Error callback.